# undefined method `paginate' for #<HomeController:0xb498fa30> in sunspot rails with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari, sunspot-rails

My controller code is

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Product) do
    fulltext params[:search]
    paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
  end
  @search_products = @search.results
```

It gives me an error

```
undefined method `paginate' for
```

For pagination I use kaminari gem. It works fine just in case with sunspot it gives an error

Comment: Are you pagination on @search_products or @search?

Comment: Have you installed your gem paginate? For example will_paginate or kaminari.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're ordering the gems correctly in your Gemfile, as order matters for these specific gems:

```
  gem 'kaminari'
  gem 'sunspot_rails'
```

Then, you want to paginate on @search:

```
  <ul>
    <% @search.results.each do |r| %>
    <li><%= r.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <%= paginate @search %>
```

Comment: Any feedback on the answer?